# Best way to add methods to a Class in execution time

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have to add methods to Class in execution time.

```
class ExtendableClass
end
```

The methods to add are declared in independent Classes.

```
module ExtensionClassOne
  def method_one
  end
end

module ExtensionClassTwo
  def method_two
  end
end
```

I'm looking for an (elegant) mechanism to add all the *extension class* methods into the `ExtendableClass`.

## Approach 1

I'm thinking in *explicily* include the *extension classes* like:

```
ExtendableClass.send( :include, ExtensionClassOne )
ExtendableClass.send( :include, ExtensionClassTwo )
```

but it looks a little forced to have to call this private method every time I define a new *extension class*.

## Approach 2

So I was looking for an *automatic* way to `include` this methods into my `ExtendableClass` class.

I'm thinking in declare an specific ancestor for this *extension classes*:

```
class ExtensionClassOne < Extension
  def method_one
  end
end
```

and then I'd need a mechanism to know **all the childs of a class**... something like the oposite of [ancestors](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-ancestors).

Once I have this list I can easily `ExtendableClass.include` all the list of classes. Even if I have to call to the private method here.

## Approach 3

Also inheriting from the `Extension` class and **detect in declaration time when this class is used as ancestor**. In the way that the [ActiveSupport.included method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html#method-i-included) works, like an *event binding*. Then make the `include` there.

Any solution for implement **approach 2** or **approach 3**? Do you recommend **approach 1**? New approachs?

Comment: Should the instance methods of the extension class be instance or class methods in the extendable class? And must the extension classes be classes, or can they be modules?

Comment: Your first method won't even execute because `ExtensionClassOne` & `ExtensionClassOne` are classes not modules.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall you're right, updated.

Comment: @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh I have changed the extension classes and they are now modules. The finish behavior I'm looking for is to be able to call `ExtendableClass.new.method_one`, `ExtendableClass.new.method_two` ...

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out what you are trying to achieve, but if you want to add the method to the class only at the point that you try to call it, could you leverage ruby's "method missing" functionality? http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_method_missing.html

Comment: Should the class know which modules it is going to include, or should the modules know into which classes they should be pulled in? Decide this and you can extend either the class or modules with metamethods that record this information and then pull the trigger later.

Comment: @MikeyHogarth the problem is that I don't know where to find the definition of the method.. due could be an indeterminate number of _extension clases_.. I need a system to _tag_ them, to store them in some kind of `Set`...

Comment: @Phrogz the `ExtendableClass` doesn't know with modules to include.. the modules (aka _extension classes_) are the ones thouse know, I'm looking for clean _implicit_ way to make this include, or also I can move on to the _explicit_ way as I say in the _Approach 1_.

Comment: @fguillen The only way to make it fully implicit is to either automatically extend every class every time you create a new module (not a good idea). You could automatically extend a particular class everytime you create a new module (still a bad idea), but already you're no longer fully _implicit_, as you must now name the class. Better to be explicit one way or another, either as your technique or the slight variation shown in my edited answer.

Comment: I need to pickup a correct answer, can you please vote the one you like more? so I can choose the most popular one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@fguillen, you are right that the "explicit way is the cleanest approach". Since that is so, why don't you use the most "explicit" code which could be imagined:

```
class Extendable
end

class Extendable
  def method_one
    puts "method one"
  end
end

class Extendable
  def method_two
    puts "method two"
  end
end
```

...In other words, if you are defining a module which will be automatically included in a class as soon as it is defined, why bother with the module at all? Just add your "extension" methods directly to the class!

Comment: +1 I didn't think in this... it makes my `include` solution to looks stupid :). It is a good point. I can defend the `include` solution saying that I have all the power in the `plug` method.. and I can modify this implementation to change the behavior of the `pluggin` system without change all the _extension classes_..

Comment: @fguillen, you don't need to "defend" your solution, because I'm not attacking it. If you do need to do something more complex than just adding methods to a class, then yes, a more complex solution might be called for. If you don't need that flexibility *right now*, however, it would be better to start with something simple and refactor later if needed.

Comment: "defend" was only a way of talking :)

Answer (score 1):

The `included` method is actually a hook. It is called whenever you are inherited from:

```
module Extensions
  def someFunctionality()
    puts "Doing work..."
  end
end
class Foo
  def self.inherited(klass)
    klass.send(:include, Extensions) #Replace self with a different module if you want
  end
end
class Bar < Foo
end
Bar.new.someFunctionality                  #=> "Doing work..."
```

There is also the `included` hook, which is called when you are included:

```
module Baz
  def self.included(klass)
    puts "Baz was included into #{klass}"
  end
end
class Bork
  include Baz
end
```

Output:

```
Baz was included into Bork
```

Comment: This looked very nice, but I have been making tests and I have found that I can't use the `inherited` hook because only _classes_ can inherit and only _modules_ can be `included` so one thing negates the other. Also what I'm looking would be the `someFunctionality` method to be declared in `Bar` and ending with the possibility of `Foo.new.someFunctionality` because in your example `Bar` is inheriting from `Foo` so, of course, it will have a `someFunctionality` method.

Comment: @fguillen: How do they negate the other?

Comment: @ Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh: only a `Class` can inherit of other Class so only a Class can be the argument of the `inherited` hook. But only a `Module` can be the argument for the `include` method.

Comment: @fguillen: Sorry, that was a mistake. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Approach 4 would be to define a macro on class level in Object

```
class Object
  def self.enable_extension
    include InstanceExtension
    extend ClassExtension
  end
end
```

and calling this macro in all your classes you want to be extended.

```
class Bacon
  enable_extension
end

Car.enable_extension
```

This way,

- you don't have to use #send to circumvent encapsulation (Approach 1)
- you can inherit from any Class you want, because everything inherits from Object anyway (except 1.9's BasicObject)
- the usage of your extension is declarative and not hidden in some hook

Downside: you monkeypatch build-in Classes and may break the world. Choose long and decriptive names.

Comment: But the _declarative_ extension will be longer than a simple `enable_extension` call, I should declare submodules `InstanceExtension` and `ClassExtension` in my _extension class_.

Comment: Of course you can namespace the above models, and you should. With declarative I meant that you (kind of) document your implementation so  another developer (or you in 2 weeks) can still figure out what is going on.

What do yo mean with _extension class_? The extend *ed* class or the modules you extend *with*?

Comment: I like the idea of _self documented_ maybe the _inherited_ hook is too much magic. When I say _extension class_ I mean _the modules you extend with_. Still your approach is too much _verbose_. If I have to call `enable_extension` and also define inner-modules like `InstanceExtension` then I prefer to go to the explicit `include` on my _Approach 1_.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: Given your answer to my comment on the question I suppose this is not what you wanted. I see no problem with your "Approach 1" in this case; it's what I'd do. Alternatively, instead of using `send` to bypass the private method, just re-open the class:

```
class ExtendableClass
  include ExtensionOne
end
```

---

Assuming I understand what you want, I'd do this:

```
module DelayedExtension
  def later_include( *modules )
    (@later_include||=[]).concat( modules )
  end
  def later_extend( *modules )
    (@later_extend||=[]).concat( modules )
  end
  def realize_extensions # better name needed
    include *@later_include unless !@later_include || @later_include.empty?
    extend  *@later_extend  unless !@later_extend  || @later_extend.empty?
  end
end

module ExtensionOne
end

module ExtensionTwo
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.extend ClassMethods
  end
  module ClassMethods
    def class_can_do_it!; end
  end
end

class ExtendableClass
  extend DelayedExtension
  later_include ExtensionOne, ExtensionTwo
end

original_methods = ExtendableClass.methods
p ExtendableClass.ancestors
#=> [ExtendableClass, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

ExtendableClass.realize_extensions

p ExtendableClass.ancestors
#=> [ExtendableClass, ExtensionOne, ExtensionTwo, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

p ExtendableClass.methods - original_methods
#=> [:class_can_do_it!]
```

Comment: I think I didn't explain my self very well, there is something important: the `ExtendableClass` (the one I want to add methods on the air) has not any idea about how many, or which are, the names of the modules it is extended with. This is because is tricky. I have to trigger the include mechanism in the modules that extend the class. Think that this modules are like **plugins**.

Comment: @fguillen I understand. Do you understand what I mean about "reopening the class" above, and how that is equivalent to your `send`?

Comment: ah!.. yes.. you mean to write this piece of code together with every _extension class_ implementation.. suppling the `send(:include)` call.. very interesting. +1 to this part.. but the second part looks too much over-engineering. :)

Comment: @fguillen Yes, that is what I meant. The second part (below the ---) was before I saw your response. It is not applicable to your problem, but I was loathe to delete it after hard minutes of work on it ;)

Answer (score 0):

After a very interesting propositions you have done I have realized that the **explicit** way is the **cleanest** approach. If we add a few recommendations taking from your answers I think I'm gonna go for this:

```
# extendable.rb
class Extendable
  def self.plug( _module )
    include( _module )
  end
end

# extensions/extension_one.rb
module ExtensionOne
  def method_one
    puts "method one"
  end
end
Extendable.plug( ExtensionOne )

# extensions/extension_two.rb
module ExtensionTwo
  def method_two
    puts "method two"
  end
end
Extendable.plug( ExtensionTwo )

# result
Extendable.new.method_one # => "method one"
Extendable.new.method_two # => "method two"
```

Answer (score 0):

A very tricky solution, I think too much over-engineering, would be to take the **inherited hook** that @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh has commented and keep all and every child class in a `Set` and combined it with the @Mikey Hogarth proposition of **`method_missing`** to look for all this child class methods every time I call a method in the `Extendable` class. Something like this:

```
# code simplified and no tested
# extendable.rb
class Extendable
  @@delegators = []

  def self.inherited( klass )
    @@delegators << klass
  end

  def self.method_missing
    # ... searching in all @@delegators methods
  end
end

# extensions/extension_one.rb
class ExtensionOne < Extendable
  def method_one
  end
end
```

But the logic of the `method_missing` (and `respond_to?`) is gonna be very complicate and dirty.

I don't like this solution, just let it here to study it like a possibility.